# Wordpress category redirection and show post by specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, redirect, categories

I have added some categories in a menu. When I click on a category name in the menu I want to be redirected to a product page, and shown only the selected category product. How can I do this? What should the post query be?

Comment: You mean you want to see archive page with only the categorie selected?

Comment: The product page is an example. I mean specific page.

Comment: We need little bit more clarification on what you want.

Comment: Normally when you click a category name from your wordpress website you will go home page. I want when i click category name it will be redirect specific page and show here post by category name.

Comment: why not simply make a custom menu link with same name of the category but with a custom link to the post you want?

Comment: how get only specific post by category name? Good I create custom link and give url link. I need to hold category name after page request and show here post by hold category name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by creating or modifying the template file `category.php`, writing something like this :

```
<?php
$cat = get_queried_object();
wp_redirect( site_url('the-page-you-want').'#'.$cat->slug );
exit();
```

This will be redirect your category *Example* to :

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/the-page-you-want#example
```

Then you can use the hash in javascript